# PHP Array to string Multiple Submit Form

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms

```
public function query($sql, $parameters = [])
{
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    var_dump($parameters);
    return $query;
}

public function delete ($id){

    $parameters = [':id' => $id];

    $this->query('DELETE FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE ' . $this- 
    >primaryKey . ' = :id', $parameters);
}

<?php
$query = $products->findAll();

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  if (isset($_POST['id']))
 {
    $products->delete([
  ':id' => $_POST['id'],
]);
 }
  else
  {
echo "You did not choose a id.";
 }
}
 ?>

 <form action="" method="POST">
<?php
 foreach($query as $row){
 echo "<label for='product_id'>" . $row['p_name'] . " </label> <input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value = '" . $row['product_id'] . "'>";
}
  ?>
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">

 </form>
```

When I submit this form I get the error of Array to string conversion.
I suspect it's something to with with 'name' for the form although I cannot figure out why and getting somewhat confused.

Comment: because `id` is an array as you have defined it to be an array `id[]`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `[]` on the end of the name parameter of an input will instruct the browser to send each input as an element of an array rather than a single string.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' >
```

You can see whats in the array with `var_dump($_POST['id'])`. If you were just expecting a string, then remove the `[]`. Otherwise you will need to loop over each value and do something with it.

Comment: I think i found the issue, so its posting two $_POST['id] and sending that to the statement which is why I'm getting the array issue or two sets of $parameters?

Comment: its posting two lots of ids. The error you're getting is because you are trying to access the array as a string